# Read binary data from table

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql-9.2

I have PostgreSQL 9.2, with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Task"
(
  "taskID" serial NOT NULL,
  "taskType" text NOT NULL,
  "taskComment" text NOT NULL,
  "taskDate" date NOT NULL,
  "taskeImage" bytea,
  CONSTRAINT "Task_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("taskID")
)
```

The table is already filled by records. I just want to read `taskeImage` and show it in a `pictureBox1`.

Here is my try:

```
//some initial code goes here
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
pictureBox1.Image=dr[4];
conn.Close();
```

Comment: where is your C# code that you are using..?

Comment: I don't have issue with connecting to the table, but i am confused If I should save the image in the disk and then use it in pictureBox1? I feel this is not practical yah?

Comment: who said anything about connecting to the table.. you will still need to show what you have tried using C# code to get the Blob, CLOB, or Whatever Binary stored data format that is for the image into a Picture Box. you will need to show more than just that Sql Table Create Table Script.

Comment: start reading here and also do a `Google Search` if this link does not help it's pretty straight forward http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/875257-get-image-sql-put-picture-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PictureBox.Image` is of type Image and `dr[4]` will likely return a `byte[]`.  You need to create an image from the `byte []` as so:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dr[4]))
{
    pictureBox1.Image= Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```